# C Programming Why is this code showing segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c

This is my code in c
why is this code showing me segmentation fault(core dumped)
please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct participant
{
    char* name[255];
    char gender;
    char meal;
    int course;
    int phone;
} v;
int main()
{
    FILE * fp;

fp = fopen("pdetails","w");

printf("Please enter your name: ");
scanf(" %19[^\n]%*[^\n]", &v.name);
printf("Please enter your gender: ");
scanf(" %s", &v.gender);
printf("Please enter your phone number: ");
scanf("%u", &v.phone);
printf("Which course you want? Please enter course number: ");
scanf("%d", &v.course);
printf("Which meal you want?:");
scanf("%s", &v.meal);


if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("FIle not Found");}
else{
    fprintf(fp, "%19[^\n]%*[^\n] %s %u %d %s", v.name, v.gender, v.phone, v.course, v.meal);
    printf("Congratulations,Booking successfull");
}
printf("\n");
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far to debug the program? If you use a debugger, you can pinpoint the offending line. You could also read your code carefully and check each step to make sure there are isn't an obvious flaw. A segfault is caused by your program attempting to access a memory address that it doesn't own (it has no permission). Or you could add extra `printf` statements (with strings ending in `\n`) to see how far it gets before the segfault occurs.

Comment: I dunno how to do， im newbie

Comment: Now would be a perfect time to learn since you have a need for it. If you are using linux then search for a tutorial on `gdb`. Other platforms will have similar debugger tutorials. It will only take a short time to get started with a debugger and can save you hours of time.

Comment: I gave you several options. Your program has `printf` statements, so surely you know how to add some `printf` statements. Also, do you get any warnings when you compile your program? I'm supposing you do from the looks of it. If so, you should address those before trying to run the program.

Comment: In addition to the problem that @jmq pointed out, you have declared `meal` as a single character (`char meal;`) but you are attempting to read in an entire string for `meal` with `scanf("%s", &v.meal);` That's going to be a memory access issue for sure. There are a few other similar issues. `char` is a single character. If you want a string, you need an array of them, such as `char meal[10];` for a `meal` up to 9 letters (you need one more for the terminating 0 in a C string).

Comment: What is the exact output of your program? Does it give you segmentation fault right away, as soon as you run it? Does it seg-fault after any of the `scanf` lines?

Comment: Just be mindful that it can appear to run fine but still have memory violations. Not all memory access errors result in a default. Re-examine your data definitions and code carefully in light of what you've learned so far.

Comment: You cannot read the gender using %s. You must use %c

Answer (score 0):

char* name[255]; defines an array of 255 pointers.  You most likely want an array of 255 characters instead:

char name[255];

Right now you are writing to unallocated memory due to the way you defined name.

Comment: Although `char name[255]` is correct, this is not the primary cause of the problem.